# How to only show processes from single program in htop. Filter not working for VS code

Tags: shell, process-management, htop

I'm trying to filter the view in `htop` to only show the processes associated with Visual Studio Code. I launch VS code on a default install on Ubuntu with `code .` so that is the filter i'm using. In the following animated GIF you can see if i try to filter for say `chrome` to see all processes with google chrome, the view only shows chrome processes. But if I try to filter the processes for Visual Studio Code with `code`, it shows stuff from google chrome and visual studio code.

How do i make `htop` filter and show only the processes that VS code is using?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your GIF, I'm assuming the `/usr/share/code/code` process is the one you are trying to filter. To exclude other processes, use a more precise filter such as `/usr/share/code/code` instead of just `code`.